# Command "ip nhrp map multicast dynamic" is not being saved into the configuration

Tags: cisco, routing, vpn, multicast, tunnel

For some reason, my Cisco router is not saving the command "ip nhrp map multicast dynamic".  The command is recognized but not being saved to the configuration.  I am not receiving any errors.  Any idea why this is happening?

```
rtr-d1#sh run int tun1
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 327 bytes
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip vrf forwarding VRF
 ip address <network/22>
 no ip redirects
 ip mtu 1392
 ip nhrp authentication <key>
 ip nhrp network-id <id>
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1352
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel mode gre multipoint
 tunnel key <key>
 tunnel protection ipsec profile <profile>
end

rtr-d1#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
rtr-d1(config)#int tun1
rtr-d1(config-if)#ip nhrp map multicast dynamic
rtr-d1(config-if)#do sh run int tun1
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 327 bytes
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip vrf forwarding VRF
 ip address <network/22>
 no ip redirects
 ip mtu 1392
 ip nhrp authentication <key>
 ip nhrp network-id <id>
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1352
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet1
 tunnel mode gre multipoint
 tunnel key <key>
 tunnel protection ipsec profile <profile>
end

rtr-d1(config-if)#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably a default. Almost all default configurations simply do not show up in a regular `show running-config`.

The classic example is to set a switch interface to VLAN 1. You will not see that in the configuration because it is the default VLAN for a switch interface.

You can see this if set your timezone to `utc 0 0`, but you will not see that in the configuration because that is the default. If you set it to anything else, then you will see the command.

Comment: On my other router, it shows in the "running-config".  See below:

`RTR-C1#sh run int tun1
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 358 bytes
!
interface Tunnel1
 ip vrf forwarding VRF
 ip address <network>
 no ip redirects
 ip mtu 1392
 ip nhrp authentication <key>
 ip nhrp map multicast dynamic
 ip nhrp network-id <id>
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1352
 tunnel source GigabitEthernet2
 tunnel mode gre multipoint
 tunnel key <key>
 tunnel protection ipsec profile <profile>
end`

Comment: Such things change between IOS versions. Are you sure you have the _exact_ same (both major and minor) version on both?

Comment: The versions are different.  Unfortunately, that is the only difference in configurations between the working and non-working DMVPN connection.

Comment: I saw this in the Cisco documentation.

'Allows NHRP to automatically add spoke routers to the multicast NHRP mappings.

Note    
Effective with Cisco IOS XE Denali 16.3 ip nhrp map multicast dynamic is enabled by default.'

I am using 16.7.1.  Maybe that's why it doesn't show up :)

Comment: OK, it is now a default command, so you will not see it in the configurations.

Comment: See if it shows up with "show run all" which is supposed to enable the display of default configuration lines. Use at your risk, though (e.g. try it out first on a non-production device) - this command is sometimes known to crash the device.

Comment: @mere3ortal - it does!  I didn't even know about that command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to verify this default, try "show run all"

```
#show run all | inc Tunnel0|map multicast dyn

interface Tunnel0
 ip nhrp map multicast dynamic
 ipv6 nhrp map multicast dynamic
```